# Make a regex to validate integer and decimal number as well

Tags: python, regex

I am learning regex so I am trying to make regex that should validate given input as correct integer and decimal numbers with/without positive/subtract sign.

I've created regex in python:

```
([+-]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)|([+-]?[5-9]+)
```

But its not working properly. Its showing

```
# expecting left side expression of pipe-sign is running
re.search("([+-]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)|([+-]?[5-9]+)","1.1") # true correct
re.search("([+-]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)|([+-]?[5-9]+)","1.") # false correct
re.search("([+-]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)|([+-]?[5-9]+)","1") # false  correct

# expecting right side expression of pipe-sign is running
re.search("([+-]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)|([+-]?[5-9]+)","5") # true  correct
re.search("([+-]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)|([+-]?[5-9]+)","5.") # true  Wrong
re.search("([+-]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)|([+-]?[5-9]+)","5.") # true  Wrong
```

Can anyone point me out what am I doing wrong here?
Thanks

Comment: Why do you have `[5-9]` as a separate case?

Comment: just playing with these range to clear the concept.

Comment: Then you'll need to adjust the `[0-9]` as well to capture digits 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4 before the decimal: `([+-]?[0-4]+\.[0-9]+)|([+-]?[5-9]+)`

Comment: The last 2 get a match because the pattern is an alternation and the second part of it `([+-]?[5-9]+)` matches the 5 in `5.` You could update the pattern to `[+-]?(?:[0-9]+\.[0-9]+|[5-9]+(?!\S))` https://regex101.com/r/KpQZKG/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern matches the last 2 examples because it makes use of an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) where the second part `([+-]?[5-9]+)` matches the 5 in `5.`

You could for example update the pattern to make the second part not match when what is on the right side is not a dot `(?!\.)`, or perhaps asserting not a non whitespace char `(?!\S)`

As `[+-]?` is used in both patterns, you could move it outside of the alternation.

```
[+-]?(?:[0-9]+\.[0-9]+|[5-9]+)(?!\S)
```

- `[+-]?` Optional `+` or `-`
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[0-9]+\.[0-9]+` Match 1+ digits 0-9, a dot a and 1+ digits 0-9
  - `|` Or
  - `[5-9]+` Match 1+ occurrences of a digit 5-9
- `)` Close group
- `(?!\S)` Assert what is directly on the right is not a non whitespace char

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Rj6KyJ/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/o8WKoc)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the problem in my solution. I need to understand  lookahead lookbehind concept.
https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 1):

If you really are looking to validate integers with decimal numbers, you can just use the following: `^([+-]?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)$` and it should be sufficient enough. Can verify at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/5C9bgv/1).

Assuming you only want to validate decimals if there's numbers following it

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sunny for your time I really appreciate it. Your solution worked. But I'll accept "The fourth Bird" answer as it also described why my solution was not working.